# webpack configuration question about compress JavaScript and Uglyfy

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[image]

After webpack compress, I find the JavaScript file look not compress completely. How can i compress, remove the comments and blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin).

Installation:

```
npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

Usage:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: new UglifyJsPlugin({
       extractComments: true,
    }),
  }
};
```

Comment: @mengqiaohu This answer was helpful?

Comment: Yep, same the code was compressed, but run there are some strange error, It's "Minified React error #31", "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #31;", blablabla...